# Meteor JS: How to navigate to a new screen after logout?

Tags: meteor

In Meteor JS, how can I navigate to a new screen after logout? I am using accounts-ui package.

In meteor docs I see this: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_logout

But, I suppose we can use this when you implement the logout yourself.

Thanks,
Sreedhar

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere during client startup:

```
Session.setDefault("everLoggedIn", false);
```

Somewhere during first login:

```
Session.set("everLoggedIn", true");
```

Within your headingOut template's helper:

html

```
<template name="headingOut">
  {{#if show}}<p>where are you going?</p>{{/if}}
</template>
```

js

```
Template.headingOut.show= function() {
  return Session.get("everLoggedIn") && Meteor.userId() === null
}
```